# How can I find identical/duplicate images in a image bank

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

Hello I have tried imagededup library by dat tran used both cnn & hash method to find the duplicates but it is not able to catch duplicate images to the query image in the case of below type of image (have also tried rgb histogram method to find the image vector). Please help any lead or any work will be much appreciated.

Have tried https://github.com/idealo/imagededup & https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/

Thanks![image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQsNz.png)

Comment: What is the relation between question and image?

Comment: The given image is the type of image among which I want to find duplicates (I have lots of such images & I want to identify the duplicate ones) Thanks @RomeoNinov for commenting kindly help!!

Comment: for those kind of images ocr might work better, most image duplicate stuff is meant for scene images, not document ones

Comment: Thanks @juvian for replying but how am I going to find out the Ocr of these chemical diagrams most of my images are full of these in many only diagrams are there

Comment: would be nice to have a few failing examples

Comment: How much of this image needs to match? Only the chemical symbols or the text or both? Is rotation important -- that is, if the image is slightly rotated, then is that an identical match? Please clarify your matching criteria?

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicate'? It's just a repetitive image or the same shape is scanned from a different angle?

Comment: The image of the questions are taken from different sources (I mean different mobile phones ) now I have a solution bank of let's say 300 questions now if someone takes photo of the photo from his mobile phones and searches then I should be able to match and give solution whose question image and solution I am already having. If we can't match the whole question then atleast somehow crop the diagram part and match that.

Comment: You may be looking for template matching

Comment: Thank You @nathancy really thank You!! It is really helpful!!